# New Windows 2019 Server becomes unresponsive after being powered on for 6+ hours

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

I just provisioned a new physical Windows 2019 Server and it is becoming unresponsive in a very particular, odd way after being online for 6 or more hours.

It happens consistently but there are no obvious errors in the Windows Event Log (that I can discern) and the non-responsiveness is in a very particular way.

The server continues to respond via RDP and its networking seems to be working, but  the GUI - particularly Windows Explorer - stops responding and just shows the spinning icon. If I try to open Task Manager, etc. it does not open.

If I try to login via RDP again, it takes a very long time "Securing Remote Connection" and eventually gets in to a black screen.

Edit: New information - Intel vROC is prompting me to rebuild a RAID 1 volume that stores the user profile data. Seems pertinent although it doesn't say there is an error.

I suspect there may be an issue with the User Profile Service but I have no evidence to support it, I just know we changed the registry setting for where the folder is located.

When this happens I have to reboot the server using remote power management.

I realize this is a very open-ended question and very light on evidence but I really am stumped where to even begin looking for a resolution. Any tips on where to start are appreciated.

Here are the two registry settings being applied:

```
Hive HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
Key path SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList 
Value name ProfilesDirectory 
Value type REG_EXPAND_SZ 
Value data D:\Users 

Hive HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
Key path SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList 
Value name ProgramData 
Value type REG_EXPAND_SZ 
Value data %SystemDrive%\ProgramData
```

Comment: Is it a new symptom, is it a vanilla image, can you see if someupdate were installed, does an antivirus is installed (and uptodate, as often older AV dont support correctly newer OS)

Comment: @yagmoth555 it's a new system so I cannot say if it is a new symptom or not. No antivirus other than Windows Defender. No updates installed recently, and its a vanilla image of Server 2019 17663

Comment: It run virtual or physical? as such latest integration tool installed if virtual

Comment: @yagmoth555 it is a new physical server.

Comment: Dell, HP, etc ? As HP server got the prolliant support pack that update everything, and Dell got their own iso

Comment: No, it is a custom built server. It is using vROC to RAID the boot and user data drive.

Comment: May be a problem related to the video driver. You should update it and then install all drivers from official OEM sites (not let the windows ones be used).

Comment: Sounds like power settings and your server is simply going to sleep.

Comment: What build number are you running? Are you fully patched? Also, what hardware are you running on and what is your bios version?